# How can i access Object Elements in PHP

Tags: php

I have a php Script which returns the following info below. I know i can access certain parts like $result->rows or $result->metrics. But here is where i run into an issue. How could i access the resultCount under the metrics ? Tried $result->metrics->resultCount which returns me a

> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /var/www/html/PHRETS/retsphp.php on line 91 NULL

Also how can i get the size of the rows array in my result ?

```
object(stdClass)#68 (5) {
  ["rows"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#67 (4) {
      ["_id"]=>
      string(36) "5081592f-60a4-4044-95a2-5512813f4462"
      ["_type"]=>
      string(3) "mls"
      ["email"]=>
      string(24) "kingarthur@couchbase.com"
      ["interests"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(16) "African Swallows"
      }
    }
  }
  ["requestId"]=>
  string(36) "610d2e60-2b10-4079-b21b-eaecd45f97e1"
  ["status"]=>
  string(7) "success"
  ["signature"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["*"]=>
    string(1) "*"
  }
  ["metrics"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["elapsedTime"]=>
    string(12) "656.312154ms"
    ["executionTime"]=>
    string(12) "656.046498ms"
    ["resultCount"]=>
    int(1)
    ["resultSize"]=>
    int(128)
  }
}
```

Comment: `$result->metrics['resultCount']`, since `metrics` is an associative array

Comment: By the way, what is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?

Comment: African or European @Cid?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't know that

Comment: That’s just some sample data from the couchbase site

Comment: Ok how do you access now the array size of rows and then an element in the array ?

Comment: `rows` is an array that contains object. `$result->rows[0]->interests[0]` and you get `"African Swallows"`

Comment: If you got this from a [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) call, you can use the set the argument to true, so you get associative arrays only